# Is there a way to select SUM with a ST_INTERSECTS restriction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I will try to explain my problem. I'm trying to select a SUM of attributes on a column with an ST_intersect restriction with this expression;

```
with inter as (
select
    planet_osm_point.way pw,
    (select sum (planet_osm_point.osm_id)
    from planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_point
    where st_intersects (planet_osm_point.way, planet_osm_polygon.way)) as sum1
    from planet_osm_point
    )
    select pw, sum1
    from inter, planet_osm_point
    group by pw, sum1
```

This returns me the same SUM of all osm_id for each planet_osm_point.way. I want to sum only the osm_id that intersects with the polygon and group by planet_osm_point.way.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a simple spatial join would suffice, e.g.

```
SELECT pol.way, sum(poi.osm_id)
FROM planet_osm_point poi, planet_osm_polygon pol
WHERE ST_Intersects(poi.way,pol.way)
GROUP BY pol.way
```

Comment: Thats right, thanks! But what if the column to sum comes from another table from the same bbdd?

Comment: @J.Patordi you'd have to either build a `JOIN` or add it to the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses. In case it is not possible, you might need to write a subquery :) does it answer your question?

Comment: I can't do a `JOIN` because i don't have any geom column in the table to relate with the st_intersects in the . So, the subquery that i need is of the whole SUM with the ST_intersect included?

Comment: @J.Patordi It would be best if you could add this 3rd table (not in the original post) to your question.